# Are adjectives, prepositions and verbs implied after conjunction "and"?

Tags: difference, conjunctions, implication

> I will go and see what I can do.
>
> Mobile services Switching Center(MSC) has to maintain real time data and traffic distribution on continuous basis.
>
> He studies to get success and make his parents happy.

Alternatives:

> I will go and **(I) will** see what I can do.
>
> Mobile services Switching Center(MSC) has to maintain real time data and **real time** traffic distribution on continuous basis.
>
> He studies to get success and **to** make his parents happy.

Are the alternatives have the same meanings as the original ones? Which ones should be preferred?

Answer (score 1):

I understand the alternatives to mean the same things as the originals.

The originals are shorter and (are) more likely to be used.  However there are sentences where it makes sense to use phrasing closer to the alternatives.

"I will help my son do his homework and go to bed."  Does this mean that I will go to bed, or that I will help my son go to bed? The sentence is not clear.

This sentence is clear: "I will help my son do his homework and I will go to bed."

This sentence is also clear: "I will my son to do his homework and to go to bed."

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The alternatives do have the same meaning, but the original sentences are usually preferred.

*And* signifies multiple things, and is used to avoid repetition:

> Tomorrow, I'm going **to** wake up early **and** [I'm going to] eat breakfast before I leave.
>
> In October, students' parents **and** [students'] teachers meet to discuss their performance.